# Python sorted() key function weirdness

Tags: python, key, sorting

While I was debugging some illogical behavour I came to the following weirdness in Python 2.5 *sorted()* function calls:

```
>>> aa = [10, 5, 20]
>>> sorted(range(len(aa)))
[0, 1, 2]
sorted(range(len(aa)), key=lambda a: aa[a])
[1, 0, 2]
sorted(range(len(aa)), key=lambda a: -aa[a])
[2, 0, 1]
```

First two calls work as expected, but the last one is imho simply **wrong**! It should be: [1, 2, 0].

After further experiments for trying to come to the root of the problem I came to this (does not use lambda or negation operation, but it is otherwise the same problem):

```
>>> bb = [-10, -5, -20]
>>> sorted([0, 1, 2], key=bb.__getitem__)
[2, 0, 1]
```

Even things like following don't work and show that double negation works again:

```
>>> bb = [-10, -5, -20]
>>> def fun(i):
...    return bb[i]
>>> sorted([0, 1, 2], key=fun)
[2, 0, 1]
>>> def fun2(i):
...     return -bb[i]
>>> sorted([0, 1, 2], key=fun2)
[1, 0, 2]
```

Am I losing my mind or where is the problem? Or why doesn't Python 3.x have the *cmp* argument that used to work fine (compatibility is the reason why I am not using it)?

Comment: Why is the third result wrong? The values you're sorting are `[0, 1, 2]`, and the keys are `[-10, -5, -20]`. Sorted that would result in `[-20, -10, -5]`, which gives `[2, 0, 1]` for the values...

Comment: Oops, you are all right! I don't have a clue why I tought this should return something like:
    >>>bb = [-1, -1, -1]
    >>>j = 0
    >>>for i in sorted(range(len(aa)), key=lambda a: -aa[a]):
    ...    bb[i] = j
    ...    j += 1
    >>> bb
    [1, 2, 0]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value returned by the key function acts as a proxy for the values being sorted.
So when you say

```
sorted(range(len(aa)), key=lambda a: -aa[a])
```

you are sorting `range(len(aa)`), that  is `[0, 1, 2]`,  but using the values
`-aa[0], -aa[1], -aa[2]` as the proxy values.

```
range(len(aa))   0   1   2    <-- values
aa[a]           10   5  20
-aa[a]         -10  -5 -20    <-- proxy values
```

Since -20, or `-aa[2]`, is the smallest proxy value,  its associated value 2
becomes the first element in the sorted result.

Since -10, or `-aa[0]` is the next smallest, its associated value 0 becomes the second element in the sorted result.

Finally -5, or `-aa[1]` is the last value, so 1 is the last number in the sorted result.

Thus, `sorted(range(len(aa)), key=lambda a: -aa[a])` equals `[2, 0, 1]`.

The answer Python is giving is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> the last one is imho simply **wrong**! It should be: [1, 2, 0]

In your second example, the key is `lambda a: aa[a]` which gives you the indices of the elements in increasing size order.

In the last example, the key is `lambda a: -aa[a]`. Due to the negation, this gives you the indices of the elements in *decreasing* size order.

So the last result should be `[2, 0, 1]` - it's the reverse of `[1, 0, 2]`.

In this example

```
>>> bb = [-10, -5, -20]
>>> sorted([0, 1, 2], key=bb.__getitem__)
[2, 0, 1]
```

you're getting the indices of the elements in increasing size order - `[2, 0, 1]` corresponds to `[-20, -10, -5]`.

In your last two examples, you're again getting the indices for the elements in increasing size order (`[2, 0, 1]`), or decreasing size order (`[1, 0, 2]`).

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense to me

```
>>> bb = [-10, -5, -20]
>>> sorted([0, 1, 2], key=bb.__getitem__)
[2, 0, 1]  ==> corresponds to bb.__getitem__ of [-20, -10, -5]
```

Comment: i've never seen python print `==> corresponds to bb.__getitem__ of [-20, -10, -5]`

Comment: Neither have I seen people who seem to speak two languages :)  

(Apologies for having fun on SO! Resuming grumpy face! )